# Did Harry and his friends receive the Order of Merlin after Voldemort’s defeat?

Tags: harry-potter

After the death of Voldemort in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, was the **Order of Merlin** awarded to Harry, Ron, Hermione and also their friends?

Is there any reference for it?

Comment: They would have been happier with 5000 points each to Gryffindor. :D

Comment: Whomever flagged this for closure as POB, [we don't close questions because they don't appear to have a canon answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184). Either they did, or they didn't; there's no opinion involved.

Comment: @phantom42 the net', many trolls there lurk.

Comment: Harry and his friends defeated you-know-who?  ***Spoiler alert!***  I haven't read the last book yet!  :-)

Comment: Its been 8 years the book released..

Comment: Didn't Harry and Ron get the Order of Merlin for defeating the Basilisk in CoS? I remember that they got 200 points for Gryffindor each, but also that they got some other reward as well.

Comment: I looked it up. Apparently, Harry and Ron got an award from the school.

Answer (score 17):

**Probably, but it’s not been confirmed.**

In some [writing for Pottermore](http://anibundel.com/2014/12/23/jk-rowlings-christmas-potter-stories-order-of-merlin/), JK Rowling gave the conditions for receiving an Order of Merlin:

> The First Class Order is awarded “for outstanding bravery or distinction” in magic, the Second Class is awarded for “achievement or endeavour beyond the ordinary”, and the Third Class is given to those who “have made a contribution to our store of knowledge or entertainment”.

Clearly the trio (along with many others) fulfil the conditions for a First Class Order. It seems likely that, under these conditions, they would have received the award, but it hasn’t been mentioned in the canon (yet).

There are no interviews or Pottermore updates that confirm or refute their OoM status. It’s likely we’ll get an answer when Pottermore reaches *Deathly Hallows*.

Comment: Pottermore has reached Deathly Hallows - though in my opinion it's a little sparse right now.

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing to indicate that he did in the entire series. The most recent detail we have comes from [Pottermore](http://pottermorehead.tumblr.com/post/102669912508/remus-lupin):

> Remus Lupin was posthumously awarded the Order of Merlin, First Class, the first werewolf ever to be accorded this honour. The example of his life and death did much to lift the stigma on werewolves. He was never forgotten by anyone who knew him: a brave, kind man who did the best he could in very difficult circumstances and who helped many more than he ever realised.

It is important to note that awards in the Harry Potter universe, much like our own are politicized. Also from [Pottermore](http://mentalfloss.com/article/59817/15-post-harry-potter-revelations-pottermore):

> The Order of Merlin, commemorating the most famous wizard of his time, has been given since the fifteenth century.
>
> While nobody argued when Albus Dumbledore received his O.M. (First Class) for defeating the Dark wizard Grindelwald, there was a good deal of muttering in the wizarding community when Cornelius Fudge, Minister for Magic, awarded himself an O.M. (First Class) for a career that many considered less than distinguished.
>
> Other less worthy recipients of the highest class of order include Arcturus Black, Sirius Black’s grandfather, who was widely believed to have bought it by loaning the Ministry a large amount of gold.

It is possible that Harry, even if he were offered a first class Order of Merlin award, might have turned it down.

Comment: Ay reference about Snape?

Comment: Nothing official or canonical yet. There is a comment on the Harry Potter Wiki page that states: Cornelius Fudge promised to give Severus Snape the Order of Merlin, First Class, for capturing Sirius Black, then assumed to be a fugitive murderer, but Black escaped before Fudge could follow through on his word. It was later stated that the loss of this Order of Merlin hit Snape hard, and allegedly was the reason that he let it slip that Remus Lupin was a werewolf.

Comment: Didn't Lockhart get one as well?

Comment: @Zikato He had an Order of Merlin, Third Class, but it’s suspected that it was revoked after it was revealed that he was a fraud.

Comment: 3rd Class Order of Merlin, yes.

Comment: In case anyone wonders who one of the possible inspirations for Fudges OOM was: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev#Cult_of_personality

Answer (score 2):

## No

At least not within the canon sources.

[The Order of Merlin page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_Merlin) on the Potter Wiki lists several individuals who were awarded an Order of Merlin and neither Harry, nor his friends are listed as recipients.  Looking at [Harry Potter's page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter) an being presented with any reward isn't referred to.  The only thing that they seem to have received is permitting:

> those who had fought in the final battle to become Aurors without getting their N.E.W.T.s

Comment: Bear in mind that this answer may need to be revised with new activity on the Potter front!